# Is it possible to search for code snippet in specific file on Github

Tags: github, search

In my example im searching for repos that have

code snippet:`"lazyModules":` inside file: `angular.json`

Any suggestions?

Comment: no I cant. Every angular project has a angular.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are looking for is, just enter the following in the Global Search:

```
lazyModules filename:angular.json
```

And that query currently returns 61 results. You can see them [here](https://github.com/search?q=lazyModules%20filename%3Aangular.json&type=Code)

Hope this helps.